# still got error Unresolved reference even with the -keep class

Tags: kotlin, android-proguard

In the project it has a class in OptionalDependencies.kt

```
package com.xyz.demo

import android.content.Context
import com.facebook.stetho.Stetho
import com.facebook.stetho.okhttp3.StethoInterceptor
import okhttp3.Interceptor

object OptionalDependencies {

    fun initStetho(context: Context) {
        Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(context)
    }

    fun getNetworkInterceptor() : Interceptor?  = StethoInterceptor()

}
```

and in the StartActivity.kt

```
package com.xyz.demo.ui

import com.xyz.demo.OptionalDependencies
……

class StartActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private fun initStetho(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) {

        val interceptor : Interceptor? = 
                OptionalDependencies.getNetworkInterceptor()//<=== any where will get error referring the 
        ……
    }

    ……
}
```

in the build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
```

in the `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-keep class com.xyz.demo.** {*;}
```

also tried `-keep class com.xyz.demo.OptionalDependencies {*;}`

get error:
  `e:/Users/sample/src/main/java/com/xyz/demo/ui/StartActivity.kt: 
    (527, 42): Unresolved reference: OptionalDependencies`

if turn off the proguard it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess have to do a "sync" after made change to the `proguard-rules.pro`, then re-build.